# My server is 20.04.2 LTS but still on kernel 4.4.0-75 and can't boot into newer kernels

Tags: grub2, 20.04, kernel, lts, vps

My server is a Xen VPS at a hosting company with limited support so I haven't had much success talking to them about this.

When I set up the server the only image they had available was 16.04.02 LTS so I used it and then immediately upgraded it to 20.04.2 LTS however it's still running kernel 4.4.0-75 which I believe is from 2017 and I'm concerned about potential security issues.

Installed kernel packages:

```
# dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic         4.4.0-75.96                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic         5.4.0-72.80                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic         5.4.0-73.82                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic   4.4.0-75.96                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                  5.4.0.73.76                                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-virtual                  5.4.0.73.76                                          amd64        Virtual Linux kernel image
```

I ran "update-grub" and rebooted and had a downtime of several hours because the server failed to boot. I was connected via the serial console when I rebooted but the Grub timer was too short for me to interact with the menu, and when it tried to boot into 5.4.0-73 it failed and kicked me out of the console and prevented me from getting back in. If I used the "boot" option in VPS admin if I was very quick I could get back in to the console for just a moment before it kicked me out again but as mentioned the Grub timeout was too short to interact with it.

I opened a ticket with the VPS company and they got the server back up but all they did was set it to boot back into 4.4.0-75 and said that the newer kernels "didn't seem to be working"

I changed the Grub configuration to have a longer timeout and tried rebooting again.  So now I can interact with the Grub menu and get a slightly clearer picture of what's going on.  When I try to boot into 5.4.0-73 or 5.4.0-72 (including recovery mode) there's no error message, the VM just silently shuts down and I have to boot it again.

No logs are being generated for the failed boots

Perhaps there's some incompatibility between the VPS system and newer kernel branches, so I thought maybe I could stay on 4.4 and just move a a newer release of that for security, but I can't find packages

Most of the links on packages.ubuntu.com are dead

Like I thought I might need to look under Xenial packages but the linked page https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/ is a dead link

I'm also getting errors when running update-grub but I don't know if they're relevant or not; there are many Google hits but no solutions or useful information

```
# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-73-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/xvda1.
done
```

Comment: How did you directly upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04? Can you perform a fresh install? Ubuntu 20.04.2 comes with kernel 5.8.

Comment: If their only Ubuntu image is 4+ years old, then that VPS provider may not be reliable enough for you to stick with them.

Comment: I used do-release-upgrade ... I think I did it twice, from 16 to 18 and then 18 to 20.

Comment: They had an image that was just named "Ubuntu 18" but it wasn't explicitly marked LTS so I didn't try it, I used the 16 LTS, then let it upgrade to 20 LTS.  At this point I'm too far in to consider reinstalling.

Comment: I appreciate the mention of 5.8.  Since 5.4 wasn't working for me I installed the package linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic and was able to boot into it successfully.  So I am on 5.8 now!  After booting into 5.8 I uninstalled the 5.4 packages (since they never worked for me) and it uninstalled a bunch of stuff like "amd64-microcode" and "thermald" which I assume are stuff that's not needed on a virtual machine but it still makes me a little nervous about rebooting again.